# applying CSS to SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following requirements for a project:

1. use an SVG as an icon
2. apply CSS to style the SVG
3. reuse the same SVG file with different styles
4. don't have inline SVG

I have found the following 2 solutions, but they don't meet my requirements:

1. putting the SVG code inline and putting a class attribute in the SVG tag itself.
2. referencing the style sheet in the .svg file itself.

Note: Importing the svg with an object tag doesn't work. 
https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-11

Does anyone have any recommendations please?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what about using SVG <symbol> elements, make sure the children components does not have any overriding classes or inline styles set.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to decide which of your requirements you need least.

Comment: I ended up going with a non-html solution. I am using React, so I wrapped the SVG in a React component. React then passes a className as props directly to the SVG tag.